# Image data type to byte array

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, arrays

According to this [tutorial](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/125/ASP.NET-MVC-Uploading-and-Downloading-Files) , he have 'image' data type to store file bytes. Then, on download action, he just get that image data type value as `byte[]`, but I have problem in my solution.

I'm using SQL 2008, LinqToSQL.

Row screenshot

[image: DB Row]

C# screenshot

[image: c#]

Error message
[image]

P.S This is my first time to work with 'save files to db'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error clearly states, `AttchDB` is a `Binary`, not a `byte`.

You can call `.ToArray()` to get the raw `byte[]` data.